# ASP.NET MVC 4 bundles includes unexpected resource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle

I'm startin using ASP.NET MVC "Bundles and Minificatiom" feature.
That's my bundle registration code:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = false;

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Assets/bundles/css")
                .Include("~/Assets/styles/style1.css")
                .Include("~/Assets/styles/style2.css")
                .Include("~/Assets/styles/style3.css")
    );
    //....
}
```

... and in *.cshtml file it's rendered by this code:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Assets/bundles/css")
```

But, when I set *BundleTable.EnableOptimizations* = **true**, my resulting (joined and minified) css-stylesheet includes classes from **style4.css** file.

As you can see, this file isn't included in bundle. Where is my mistake?

Comment: You sure there aren't any wild-card includes after `//....` which causes `style4.css` to be included?

Comment: @HenkMollema, it hasn't wildcard includes. Ony *strict* files definition.